# CodeIgniter custom_result_object class parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

In my model I have:

```
function select_by_limit($start, $limit) {
    $this->db->from($this->_table.' a');
    $this->db->join('zone b', "a.id_zona = b.id_zona", 'left');
    $this->db->join('tip_proprietate c', "a.id_tip_proprietate = c.id_tip_proprietate");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result->custom_result_object('Proprietati');
}
```

So I use custom object class Proprietati. But how can I send a parameter so I can get it in constructor?

```
public function __construct($resolution = 270){
    $this->_resolution = $resolution;
}
```

Comment: Is the `Proprietati` class loaded as a ci library?

Comment: Your only option is to write a `MY_DB_result` class  in `application/core` and override `custom_result_object()`. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WpUTt9uK like this.

Comment: So that is the only option to pass that resolution?

Comment: @IonVasile you can also get a result_array() and load your class as library. There you have the option to pass options in your constructor but you may need to alter your constructor implementation a little bit to add the other parameters as well.

Comment: Hmmm, this is like a patch. I would like to found a dry solution to parse objects from database.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
class foo extends CI_Controller {
    protected $_resolution;

    public function __construct($resolution = 270){
        $this->_resolution = $resolution;
    }
```

To pass $resolution to the model function

```
public function using_model($start, $limit, $this->resolution);
```

In the model

```
function select_by_limit($start, $limit, $resolution) {
    //whatever happens here....
```